# Automatically shutdown after recovering from suspend

Tags: linux, linux-mint, shutdown, suspend

Environment:

- OS: Linux Mint 19.2
- Laptop: XPS13 9360 with the latest BIOS

Problem:

I cannot understand why but if I close the lib, my laptop will go suspend and when I reopen the lib, it will recover. Here is the problem, when it recovers from suspend, it will automatically shut down after a few seconds. It's really strange :(

Any advice is appreciated!